# How to write vector equation of a cylinder in 3D space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

One of the practice problems I was doing is:

Find the vector equation of the surface of cylinder with radius $a>0$ and the axis that goes through the origin and has the direction of vector $\overrightarrow{e}$.

The solution is: $|\overrightarrow{r} \times \overrightarrow{e}|=a$, but I have no idea how to derive it. I would appreciate if someone would explain to me how to get that (I was thinking about it a lot, but it is completely different from a vector equation of a line and I have no idea what to do).

I would also like to know how to get the more general vector equation of a cylinder, whose axis does not go through the origin. And I was thinking if I could perhaps derive the vector equation of a circle in 2D space, but I had no success with that either, so I would also appreciate any help with that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Oops, I mistyped, I'll fix that immediately. Thanks for noticing, @Théophile.